# sql server convert function behave differently on different machine

Tags: sql-server

When I run this query on one machine it works perfectly:

```
select convert(datetime, '2021-01-18 00:00:00.000')
```

But in another machine, I get an out of range error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: SQL server uses the Windows local by default, what happens if you *explicitely* `set dateformat` or use the correct convert format/style

Comment: I just ran this on every sql server available at dbfiddle.uk and had no issues. What's up with the machine that is throwing the error? Is it actually this string literal that is causing it or you are running this `convert()` against a column with many records?

Comment: It is the default language of the login that you are using that will control this - not the windows locale. On one machine you might be logging is as US and another UK English for example

Comment: it is exactly this code that i run without applying any conversion.i know it is related to local. the local was diffrent. and we changed the new server after installation of sql server but still this query give different outcoume

Comment: should we reinstall the sql server in new machine to give the same results?

Comment: Assuming your datetime string is actually a parameter to your query, the **best** solution is to properly parameterize your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That format is invalid when using certain `language` and `dateformat` settings. Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=49ab04070dcc621e7125e8d5851612f7) and [another example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6eec1259bfe591fe1e56bea8dcb32277).

```
SET DATEFORMAT YDM;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-18 00:00:00.000');
```

..or...

```
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-18 00:00:00.000');
```

Both yield:

> Msg 242 Level 16 State 3
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

You do not need to reinstall SQL Server to fix this, as it's not the installation that is the problem.

The real solution is to always use a safe, unambiguous format - see the links in the "Regional formats" section of [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

[These all succeed](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ba259bcf139037fe7b4f581d34e3ea9), for example:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YDM;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-18T00:00:00.000');
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20210118 00:00:00.000');
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20210118');
```

...and...

```
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-18T00:00:00.000');
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20210118 00:00:00.000');
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20210118');
```

If you can't control the format of the string, then another option is to manually apply these settings first (this should work on whatever machine it's currently failing for you):

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
SET LANGUAGE us_english;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-18 00:00:00.000');
```

This is obviously not the optimal solution.

The issue may also be that the login connecting to the server with wrong results has their default language set to something other than the default US English (more than half of the languages SQL Server supports interpret `yyyy-mm-dd` as `yyyy-dd-mm`, for reasons I will never understand).

If this is the case, you may be able to fix this login...

```
ALTER LOGIN [login name] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english];
```

...but unless you are switching from `british`, this will have other consequences for them, such as language of warnings and errors, interpretation of other data like numeric, and so on. It also won't last if the login changes their setting back, and it won't affect any future logins that are created with a non-default language (or any logins that later change in the "wrong" direction).

**So I still feel like *fixing the way the ambiguous string is interpreted* is not the answer.**

In the comment you say you have code that does this:

```
WHERE datetime_col >= '2018-01-12'
```

In which case you can either:

(a) convert to datetime with the 120 style, overriding regional/language settings:

```
WHERE datetime_col >= CONVERT(datetime, '2018-01-12', 120)
```

(b) convert to date, which doesn't care about regional/language settings:

```
WHERE datetime_col >= CONVERT(date, '2018-01-12')
```

(c) I still think the best (and easiest!) answer is to simply not use an ambiguous format that requires workarounds and/or every login to be created a specific way and never override session settings:

```
WHERE datetime_col >= '20180112'
```

Comment: My problem is that we have o lot of code for cube partitions for example this one:SELECT MIN(Snapshot_Date) AS MInDay
FROM [dbo].[View_A]
WHERE Snapshot_Date >= '2018-01-12' AND Snapshot_Date < '2019-01-01' and because of this behavior it return different results. how we can just the configuration of two sql server with the same configuration.

Comment: @user3587785 You need to fix the code to not have dashes in the dates. Or use `>= CONVERT(datetime, '2018-01-12', 120)` but isn't it just easier to remove the dashes? Why are date string literals hard-coded into "lot of code"?

Comment: many thanks, @Aron right now the language is the same(which at the beginning was not) then why it has different outcomes.I wonder if  is the any way (config level ) other than  code change(because i have to search all databases/sp/.. to make sure  everything would work the sam)?

Comment: I mean basically we are just migrating to new server and i prefeer not to search for every stored procedure or cube partitions to find if the results would be different and going to change codes.

Comment: @user3587785 You fix this by fixing the code, not changing some server-level config option or reinstalling SQL Server.

Comment: I understand your point. but now the lagnuage setting is the same for both server then why we get different result with the same data and the same query: SELECT MIN(Snapshot_Date) AS MInDay FROM [dbo].[View_A] WHERE Snapshot_Date >= '2018-01-12' AND Snapshot_Date < '2019-01-01'

Comment: What do you mean "for both server"? Where do you change the language for the server? What's happening is that either the _login_ has a different default language _on that server only_ or is overriding either language or dateformat (or both) at the session level. You can fix that login if it's the former, but that may be undesirable and isn't a permanent solution anyway (because they may switch back and new logins could also get a different default language).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aaron the logins default language was the problem. after changing the logins default language problem solve.

Comment: @user3587785 ...until they change it back or a new login gets created with a different default language. The real fix is to stop using formats that are affected by these things in the first place.